# How do I Format Response if object key exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

**Description**

I've got a response coming back from a Service which I am calling on my NODE back-end.

I am then transforming my response in a more friendly format, like so;

```
export default (response) => {
const {
    limit,
    debt,
    outstanding
} = response.object;

const transformedData = {
    outstanding: retrieveAmounts(outstanding),
    limit: retrieveAmounts(limit),
    debt: retrieveAmounts(debt)
};
return _omitBy(transformedData, value => value === null);
};
```

As you can see I am running a function `retrieveAmounts(value)` on each item.

```
const retrieveAmounts = ({ amount, code }) => ({
amount: isStringDefined(amount) ? amount : null,
currencyCode: isStringDefined(code) ? code : null
});
```

**Update**

`retrieveAmounts()` in turn calls `isDefinedString` which checks the type and length provided, like so;

```
const isDefinedString = value => typeof value === 'string' && value.length > 0;
```

The problem is that while both; debt and limit are required and will always return - outstanding is not. If there is nothing to display the object key will simply not be there. 
This is when the `retrieveAmounts()` throws an error because it cannot fin `amount` or `code` of undefined - since they don't exist because the key is not there.

How can I  format the object key if it exists but return null if it does not? This way, `retrieveAmounts()` will not throw an error and I will simply provide `limit:null` to my front-end app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'undefined' cannot be destructured. You need to check whether it's undefined before destructuring.

```
let limit = {'amount': '1000', 'code': '£'}, outstanding = undefined, debt = {'amount': '900', 'code': '£'};

const retrieveAmounts = amountStruct => {
    if (typeof amountStruct === 'undefined') 
        return null;
    let {amount, code} = amountStruct;
     return {
        amount: isStringDefined(amount) ? amount : null,
        currencyCode: isStringDefined(code) ? code : null
    };
};
```

Inline following @alex35's code.

```
const retrieveAmounts = (amountStruct) => ((typeof amountStruct === 'undefined') ? null : {
    amount: isStringDefined(amountStruct.amount) ? amountStruct.amount : null,
    currencyCode: isStringDefined(amountStruct.code) ? amountStruct.code : null
});
```

Comment: I'm having issues passing the complexity rules around my linter.  Is there anywhere else we can stick that undefined check? Tried a function - breaks

Answer (score 1):

You could put a default parameter inside your `retrieveAmounts` function, so putting undefined inside your retrieveAmounts function doesn't produce an error.

```
const retrieveAmounts = (outstanding = { amount: null, code: null }) => ({  // << here
    amount: isStringDefined(outstanding.amount) ? amount : null,
    currencyCode: isStringDefined(outstanding.code) ? code : null
});
```

Comment: That doesn' work :-( it takes amount and code outside of the scope and I get `ReferenceError: amount is not defined`

Comment: I updated it with `outstanding.amount` and `outstanding.code`. If parameter is undefined, I get `{amount: null, currencyCode: null}`.

Comment: I didn't accept your answer as the above answer allows the return of limit as null where's the defaults here return the object along with their properties. +1 though for the helpful input